# Android Studio: attach source for external C library

Tags: android-studio, clion

My (Kotlin) Android Studio project uses a pre-built, external library written in C++.  I have the source for that library and would like to attach it so that I can navigate the source while debugging.  I've looked around in both Studio and CLion documentation and have not found anything relevant.

Is it possible?

Comment: This might work, but it is pretty annoying: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620947/how-to-navigate-to-source-code-in-linked-libraries-in-clion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 10/2022, it is not possible.

Here is an abbreviation of the response to feature request:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/256905232

> Changed status:  Assigned  →  Infeasible
>
> The team has considered this use case in the past, and have decided
> that it is not a priority at the moment.